# Extract only the <key> in plist using bash in Mac

Tags: linux, mac, script, xcode, plist

I want to extract the key value in Countries in the following plist.
For example, I want the output file contains the following keys only:

`USA
ITALY`

But if I use the following script, It will print all the nested element under Countries including: 
           Capital
           Washington DC
           Continent
           North America
        .

How can I modify the script so that it will only print the keys under Countries?

`output=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy "$infoplistPath/Info.plist" -c "Print :Nation:Countries")`

Here is the plist:

`<dict>
<key>Nation</key>
<dict>
   <key>Countries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>USA</key>
        <dict>
           <key>Capital</key>
           <string>Washington DC</string>
           <key>Continent</key>
           <string>North America</string>
        </dict>
           <key>Italy</key>
        <dict>
           <key>Capital</key>
           <string>Rome</string>
           <key>Continent</key>
           <string>Europe</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
 </dict>
</dict>`

Comment: The answer was posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851738/extract-only-the-key-in-plist-using-bash-in-mac